# Update a table using info from a second table and a condition from a third table in Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, join, sql-update

My current code is as follows

```
UPDATE product_template
SET 
listprice = product_uom.factor * product_template.list_price
FROM product_uom
INNER JOIN product_template ON product_uom.id = product_template.uom_id
INNER JOIN product_product ON product_product.id = product_template.id  
WHERE product_product.manufacturer = 2646
```

As I understand line 1 specifies which table I want to update.
then I specify that I want to update the column named list_price which is in product_template using 2 numeric columns.
I specify the second table which has a column with a numeric value I need in order to update my column from the table that is going to be updated.
I specify the inner join of the table that is going to be updated and the table that has the info I need to do so.
I join the table that is going to be updated with the table that has a column which I need as a condition for the update to happen.
the last line states the condition that must be met in order for the update to happen in that row.

As it is, if I try to run this code in postgresql I get the following error
ERROR:  table name "product_template" specified more than once

I only use product_template to specify which tabkle will be updated and twice more to create the inner joins, what is the correct way of of updating this table while using information from 2 different tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use the `JOIN...ON` syntax to join to the table that is being updated to the rest of the tables.  You have to move those join conditions into the `WHERE` clause, and remove the updated table itself `product_template` from the `FROM` clause.

```
UPDATE product_template
SET 
list_price = product_uom.factor * product_template.list_price
FROM product_uom, product_product
WHERE product_product.manufacturer = 2646 and
   product_uom.id = product_template.uom_id and
   product_product.id = product_template.id
```

(This is assuming you do *not* want to do a self join, which it seems you don't.  If you do want a self-join, then you need to assign a table alias, just like with non-update self joins.)

Answer (score 0):

Read this link: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html

> **from_list**
>  A list of table expressions, allowing columns from other
>   tables to appear  in the WHERE condition and the update expressions.
>   This is similar to the list of tables  that can be specified in the
>   FROM Clause of a SELECT statement.
>   **Note that the target table must not appear in the from_list, unless you intend a self-join
>
>   (in which
>   case it must appear with an alias in the from_list).**

You need to use an alias to assign different name to second `product_template` in your query, and replace `product_template` with this alias in places where you want to refer to this second table.
PostgreSql doesn't know which one `product_template` you mean in below places in the query (the first, or the second one). I don't know too.

```
UPDATE product_template
SET ....... * product_template.list_price
...........
INNER JOIN product_template ON ...... = product_template.uom_id
INNER JOIN  ..........  ON ...... = product_template.id
```